# Viewing long error responses in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, macos-sierra

When long query error messages are logged in the Response column of the Action Output table/tab, many do not fit the width of the column and are not word-wrapped, so the message gets truncated. In searching for a solution, I came across [the release notes for a previous version](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-5-2-17.html) that appears to address this exact problem:

> On the Output tab of the SQL Editor, it was not possible to properly view the contents of the Action and Message columns, if the text exceeded the standard column width.
>
> MySQL Workbench has now added a detail panel, so that long messages can be easily viewed. (Bug #51040)

The detail panel described in those notes does not seem to exist in version 6.3, and they were for 5.2. Does anyone know what happened to this feature? Is there another way to view long messages (besides copying them and pasting them into another editor) in 6.3?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply hover with the mouse over the message and will get a tooltip after a moment with the full text. Alternatively, you can just copy it and paste it in an editor. This is particularly useful if you search for something in the message.

Comment: Did you try this in macOS? Hovering does not produce a tooltip.

Comment: That's weird. How can this stop working? OK, then only copy to editor is a help here.

Comment: Definitely weird. I've never worked with an IDE that is so bad about displaying error messages.

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, I can right-click and select Copy Row and paste it into a notepad program, but then I have to look for the Error again or delete the rest of the message to make the error readable. Not easy but it seems to be the only way to see the full message as the column will only expand so far.